# Do 90% of all German Chemistry graduates start a PhD?

Tags: phd, germany, chemistry

Can someone corroborate the fact above? If it’s true, how did it come to such a high number, do they have some slots reserved, or is it easy to enter German PhD programs? Would it also be easy for foreign graduates (in my case chemistry) to join a German PhD program?

Source 1 ([German Wikipedia](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chemiestudium)):

> Rund 91 % der frisch diplomierten Chemiker begannen nach ihrem Abschluss mit der Promotion.
>
> 91 % of the recent chemistry graduates enrolled in a PhD program. [This does not imply they completed it.]

Source 2 ([Universität Duisburg–Essen](https://www.uni-due.de/isa/fg_naturwiss/chemie/chemie_hs_frm.htm)):

> Wie jährlich durchgeführte Erhebungen der Gesellschaft Deutscher Chemiker (GDCh) zeigen, begannen in den letzten Jahren über 80 % der Absolventen nach dem Diplom bzw. Master mit einer Promotion.
>
> According to yearly inquiries by the Gesellschaft Deutscher Chemiker (GDCh) [Society of German chemists], 80 % of diploma or master graduates enrolled in a PhD program in the last years.

Comment: can you cite the source of this information ?

Comment: @krammer: cannot find a source for all nat. sci., only for the Chemistry graduates. I adapted the question accordingly.

Comment: i don't have any data to confirm this, only three hypotheses: 1a) on the supply side, the funding for "wissenschaftliche Mitarbeiter" (research fellow) positions in the natural sciences is above average. 1b) equally on the supply side, there are less employment constraints, for example, positions don't have to be publicly advertised, perhaps because positions in the nat. sci. rely less on outside money (drittmittel) than average. 2) on the demand side, a PhD in the nat. sci. makes more of a difference in the labour-market, also for industry jobs, than, say, in the humanities.

Answer (score 4):

According to the [German Chemical Society](https://www.gdch.de/index.php?eID=tx_nawsecuredl&u=0&file=fileadmin/downloads/Ausbildung_und_Karriere/Karriere/PDF/gdch-2012chemie.pdf&t=1391970038&hash=1df38456259e085387965d2b422d35ce4e0bf339), apparently 90% of master's recipients in chemistry **do** start doctoral studies afterwards.

Partly this is because PhD "admission" is largely not an admissions process at all in Germany. Individual faculty members who receive grants can hire master's recipients as "Wissenschaftliche Mitarbeiter" (literally "scientific worker," but "research assistant" is a better translation). They can do this without recourse to going through a department-level admissions process, and can skip outside advertising altogether if they have an internal candidate they can appoint instead. And, since many students follow the rule of "Was der Bauer nicht kennt, isst er nicht"—"What the farmer doesn't know, he doesn't eat"), many students do their entire education at one school.

So yes, it's much easier to get a PhD position if you're already in Germany.

Comment: this explains (very well) why many German students start a PhD. but since it applies across disciplines, it can't explain why the high number of PhD candidates only occurs in the natural sciences (rer nat.). or am i missing anything?

Answer (score 0):

The system in Germany differs from the PhD system in some points:

- Usually there are no (or very little) courses you have to take.
- One assumes, you are capable of doing your own research projects (at least after a year or so)
- You are mainly involved in projects running at one institute - and it's up to the chairperson to select the person.
- You might have to do some work which is not (or just slightly) related to your PhD, like teaching courses, taking over part of the administrative work, etc. (this strongly depends on the group you are in).
- Often it is requested that you write one or more grant poropsals (and be successful so that the person coming after you is financed). This also depends on the group you are in.

I know of several proessors who say "you are employee of the institute and you have the opportunity to use some of the time to work on your PhD". You should make sure, your "work for the institute" overlaps significantly with your PhD-topic, otherwise you won't succeed.

One reason why so many people in Chemistry have a PhD is, there are so many students and industry can just select the ones with the best qualification. I'm not very familiar with the situation in Chemistry, but I now some biologists and there is the same mechanism working.

In other fields, it is quite different, e.g. in engineering, computer science, etc. the PhD-rates are significantly lower (I don't have numbers, but my guess would be <15%).

One tipp at the end: If you can bring some money (e.g. a DAAD-scholarship), I expect your chances to be quite good.

Comment: While a lot of this is true, it doesn't answer the question.  And I disagree with your last point: one German professor I know *rejected* a candidate who came with their own funding.  All his other PhD students were employed at the university, and he didn't want a group where some PhD students were employed and unionised, and others at a (much lower!) grant from a foreign source.

Comment: Therefore I did not say "you will get ite position". But it helps (and of yourse it's good to ask in advance). I got very good PhD candidates this way.
The reason for my answer was, it explains a bit the underlying question of "how does the German PhD system work". I would rather consider it as a side note than an answer...